# Stripe with Salesforce (using LWC)

Tags: lightning-web-components, locker-service, stripe

Is it possible to integrate to Stripe using a Salesforce LWC? I am having an issue trying to submit a valid test card to Stripe. Is LockerService blocking this somehow?

I have the below LWC code, based on the 'Accept a Payment' Stripe docs, which lets me mount the div element but does nothing when the Pay button is clicked and stripe.confirmCardPayment() is called. The `handlePay` method is called ok but the last line `console.log(result)` is not called and there is no error. FYI I created the `clientSecret` (obfuscated here as well as the public key) separately using the paymentIntent flow and just copied it into this code for testing.

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
import { loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import StripeJS from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/stripe2";

export default class StripeTest2 extends LightningElement {
    initialised = false;
    stripe;
    cardElement;
    clientSecret = "pi_XXXX";

    async renderedCallback() {
        if (this.initialised) {
            return;
        }
        this.initialised = true;

        await Promise.all([loadScript(this, StripeJS)]).catch((error) => console.error(error));

        const cardWrapper = this.template.querySelector("[data-id='card-element']");

        // setup Stripe.js and Elements
        this.stripe = Stripe("pk_test_XXXX");
        const elements = this.stripe.elements();

        // setup card Element
        this.cardElement = elements.create("card", {});
        this.cardElement.mount(cardWrapper);
    }

    async handlePay(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        const cardElement = this.cardElement;

        const result = await this.stripe.confirmCardPayment(this.clientSecret, {
            payment_method: {
                card: cardElement,
                billing_details: {
                    name: "Jenny Rosen"
                }
            }
        });

        console.log(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added the `lwc:dom="manual"` directive to your `[data-id='card-element']` tag in the template?

Comment: You can try to set your lwc component with api version 39 a or lower to avoid the locker service limitations

Comment: @LironC it looks like the earliest API version that can be used now is v45.0 (which has the Locker Service and the same issue).

Comment: @adriancg, yes I am using lwc:dom="manual" but no joy.

Comment: @Breandán Sorry. you are right. I had similar issue with other external JS library, but it was in aura component. Seems for LWC we cannot use this api

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same problem that you. I can't find a way to make Stripe work with LWC however a workaround might be using a Visualforce Page instead. If you include a `<script>` tag in your visualforce page, you could mount and create listeners to your elements so they can handle payments.

```
 card.mount("#c-example-card-element");
      checkoutButton = document.getElementById("checkout-button");
      checkoutButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        // console.log("Click!");
        stripe
          .confirmCardPayment("{!clientSecretKey}", {
            payment_method: {
              card: card,
              billing_details: {
                address: {
                  city: "{!city}",
                  country: "US",
                  line1: "{!address}",
                  line2: "{!city}",
                  postal_code: "{!zipCode}",
                  state: "{!cityState}"
                },
                email: " {!email}",
                name: " {!name}",
                phone: " {!phone}"
              }
            }
          })
          .then(function (result) {
            if (result.error) {
              // Show error to your customer (e.g., insufficient funds)
              console.log(result.error.message);
            } else {
              console.log("YES! SUCCESS");
              // The payment has been processed!
              if (result.paymentIntent.status === "succeeded") {
                console.log("PAYMENT MADE! SUCCESS");
              }
            }
          });
```